# MYSQL calculate volume from raw material units on raw materials in stock

Tags: mysql, calculation

I'm trying to figure out the calculation for finding the stock required and also display the volume output if it cant reach the max tresshold in this case volume '1000'.

I will try my best to explain it as plain as possible. (tables and columns are in dutch)

Example:

To produce a volume of 1000 I need multiple raw materials. The raw materials have different totals to go in the 'cooking pot' (and to reach 1000, aqua is added but thats a side note).

1000 is the base for calculating the numbers in the table **receptgrondstoffen**

First I have the table with the recipe called 'naam' (name)

table: **recepten**

```
CREATE TABLE `recepten` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `administratieid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `omzetgroepid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `artikelgroepid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `artikelnummer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'gevuld vanuit snelstart',
  `factornummer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `eannummer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `notitie` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `volume` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000,
  `onderzoek` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `viscositeit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phwaarde` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dichtheid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `thtmaanden` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `voorraadcontrole` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `drempelwaarde` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `recepten` (`id`,`administratieid`,`omzetgroepid`,`artikelgroepid`,`artikelnummer`,`factornummer`,`eannummer`,`naam`,`notitie`,`volume`,`onderzoek`,`viscositeit`,`phwaarde`,`dichtheid`,`thtmaanden`,`voorraadcontrole`,`drempelwaarde`) VALUES (1,0,0,702,300001,'122','','test','test',1000.00000,1,'1','2','3',36,0,1);
INSERT INTO `recepten` (`id`,`administratieid`,`omzetgroepid`,`artikelgroepid`,`artikelnummer`,`factornummer`,`eannummer`,`naam`,`notitie`,`volume`,`onderzoek`,`viscositeit`,`phwaarde`,`dichtheid`,`thtmaanden`,`voorraadcontrole`,`drempelwaarde`) VALUES (2,0,0,704,300002,'1234','','test1','test',1000.00000,1,'1','2','3',36,0,100);
```

Second tables are the recipe items that go into the 'cooking pot'. There are 2 raw material lines. Both have a number of 100 so for each volume of 1000, 100 units from both are required. If I change the volume to 100 then 10 units from both are required.

table: **receptgrondstoffen**

```
CREATE TABLE `receptgrondstoffen` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receptid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `grondstofid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `aantal` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000,
  `percentage` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `receptgrondstoffen` (`id`,`receptid`,`grondstofid`,`aantal`,`percentage`) VALUES (2,1,1,100.00000,10.00000);
INSERT INTO `receptgrondstoffen` (`id`,`receptid`,`grondstofid`,`aantal`,`percentage`) VALUES (3,1,2,100.00000,10.00000);
```

The 'grondstofbatch' tables is the raw material quantity that's been bought

Table: **grondstofbatch**

```
CREATE TABLE `grondstofbatch` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grondstofid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `leveranciersid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `batchnummer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `datum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `thtdatum` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `voorraad` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `grondstofbatch` (`id`,`grondstofid`,`leveranciersid`,`batchnummer`,`datum`,`thtdatum`,`voorraad`) VALUES (1,1,4,'1224-4',1662626077,1665266400,100);
INSERT INTO `grondstofbatch` (`id`,`grondstofid`,`leveranciersid`,`batchnummer`,`datum`,`thtdatum`,`voorraad`) VALUES (2,1,3,'#34423',1662626904,1663970400,300);
INSERT INTO `grondstofbatch` (`id`,`grondstofid`,`leveranciersid`,`batchnummer`,`datum`,`thtdatum`,`voorraad`) VALUES (3,2,3,'#00931',1662626904,1663970400,200);
```

Volume is the kicker.

What i want, if I use volume amount lets say in this case its 3000 I get a return that the max volume be created is X because not all raw materials are present.

The base is 1000 = 100 so for 3000 it is 300 and only 1 raw material has the required stock. So that means it will be max 2000 volume. And if there is no volume that can be produced then 0.

results;

```
CREATE TABLE `results` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `volume` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity_needed` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `stock` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `result` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (1,1000,'100,100','400,200',1000);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (2,400,'100,100','400,200',2000);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (3,3000,'100,100','400,200',2000);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (4,500,'100,100','400,200',500);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (5,500,'50,75','400,200',500);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (6,500,'50,75','25,75',250);
INSERT INTO `results` (`id`,`volume`,`quantity_needed`,`stock`,`result`) VALUES (7,500,'30,30','25,75',416);
```

Hope there is a SQL wizard that can help me out.

Comment: Please provide some sample data using tables vs. images. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GRIV like this?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. If you can add a table showing the output you expect as well, that would be great.

Comment: @griv I dont have a table for output. I need a quiry based on above to show the volume that can be produced. So in this case volume 1000 can be produced because raw materials are in stock. If I put in volume 3000 I cant, because the max volume that can be produced is 2000. because batch stock from one raw material is 200

Comment: Understood, you can create a fabricated table/result though that can show us what you expect. You can make it up. It'll just speed things up for everyone involved.

Comment: @GRIV changed it with result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

```
SELECT r.id, 
 r.volume,
 group_concat(rg.aantal ORDER BY rg.id SEPARATOR ',') quantity_needed,
 group_concat(g.voorraad ORDER BY rg.id SEPARATOR ',') stock, 
 min(floor(g.voorraad/rg.aantal)) * r.volume result
FROM recepten r INNER JOIN receptgrondstoffen rg
  on r.id = rg.receptid
 inner join grondstofbatch g
  on g.id = rg.grondstofid
GROUP BY r.id, r.volume
```

You can see it with your sample data [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SVXi119m).

(I am possibly misunderstanding your problem since your result data doesn't seem to match your sample data).

The idea here is that, for each recepten, calculate `min(floor(grondstofbatch.voorraad/receptgrondstoffen.aantal))`. `Floor` since we want an integer (e.g. if we need 100 units for the recipe and actually have 250 units, floor(250/100) = 2 possible batches). `Min` since we want the limiting factor (e.g. it doesn't matter if one item in the recipe has enough for 20 batches if another item only has enough for 1 batch).

Hopefully this is in the ballpark of what you're looking for.

**Edited:** To handle the case where to sum the available quantities I have changed the alias g to be a subquery using the `grondstofid` table (rather than just the straight `grondstofid` table). I also realize I was likely joining the `grondstofid` table incorrectly above (`g.id = rg.grondstofid` rather than `g.grondstofid = rg.grondstofid`).

```
SELECT r.id, 
 r.volume,
 group_concat(rg.aantal ORDER BY rg.id SEPARATOR ',') quantity_needed,
 group_concat(g.voorraad ORDER BY rg.id SEPARATOR ',') stock, 
  min(floor(g.voorraad/rg.aantal)) * r.volume result
FROM recepten r INNER JOIN receptgrondstoffen rg
  on r.id = rg.receptid
 inner join (SELECT grondstofid, sum(voorraad) voorraad FROM grondstofbatch GROUP BY grondstofid) g
  on g.grondstofid = rg.grondstofid
GROUP BY r.id, r.volume
```

Please take a look at a [fiddle of this version](https://dbfiddle.uk/PTB4_g2-)

Comment: first off thank you very much it's in the right direction! In the result data the last row is I think the best example. If I have a base volume 500 and the quantity needed from 2 raw materials is 30/30 but the stock is for the first 25 and the second 75 thats means calculate on the lowest stock number. In that case 25. 500 / 30 * 25 = 416.6666666 So I can produce a volume of 416. But if the base volume is 500 and the value that I can produce is => 500 it stays 500 or if one of them has stock 0 then 0. Hope this helps a bit of explaining. (Or maybe my calculations arent right)

Comment: allready changed some things however cant get voorraad to group (sum) https://dbfiddle.uk/LYM8bjkr stock needs to be 25,75,100

Comment: What does it mean that there are 25 and 0 quantities of grondstofid=1? Should those be summed to be 25, or how are you picking 25 over 0?

Comment: Thats correct 25 and 0 needs to be summed up.They're the same raw material.

Comment: Please take a look at my new example.

Comment: you're a true legend. thanks mate